# Remove repeated substring in column and only return words in between

Tags: regex, python-3.x, pandas, str-replace

I have the following dataframe:

```
      Column1                                                                       Column2
0   .com<br><br>Finance<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>     .comFinance
1   .com<br><br>Finance<br><br><br><br><br>DO<br><br><br><br><br><br><br>   .comFinanceDO
2   <br><br>Finance<br><br><br>ISV<br><br>DO<br>DO Prem<br><br><br><br><br><br>  FinanceISVDODO Prem
3   <br><br>Finance<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>         Finance
4   <br><br>Finance<br><br><br>TTY<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>      ConsultingTTY
```

I used to following line of code to get Column2:

```
df['Column2'] = df['Column1'].str.replace('<br>', '', regex=True)
```

I want to remove all instances of "< b >" and so I want the column to look like this:

```
Column2
.com, Finance
.com, Finance, DO
Finance, ISV, DO, DO Prem
Finance
Consulting, TTY
```

Comment: `df['Column2'] = df['Column1'].str.replace('<br>', ' ', regex=True).str.strip().replace('\\s+', ', ', regex=True)`, except `<br>DO Prem<br>` is going to cause problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the following dataframe:

```py
                                                                     Column1
         .com<br><br>Finance<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
       .com<br><br>Finance<br><br><br><br><br>DO<br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
 <br><br>Finance<br><br><br>ISV<br><br>DO<br>DO Prem<br><br><br><br><br><br>
             <br><br>Finance<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
          <br><br>Finance<br><br><br>TTY<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```

- `df['Column2'] = df['Column1'].str.replace('<br>', ' ', regex=True).str.strip().replace('\\s+', ', ', regex=True)` doesn't work because of sections like `<br>DO Prem<br>`, which will end of like `DO, Prem`, not `DO Prem`.
- Split on `<br>` to make a list, then use a list comprehension to remove the `''` spaces.

  - This will preserve spaces where they're supposed to be.
- Join the list values back into a string with `(', ').join([...])`

```py
import pandas as pd

df['Column2'] = df['Column1'].str.split('<br>').apply(lambda x: (', ').join([y for y in x if y != '']))

# output
                                                                     Column1                    Column2
         .com<br><br>Finance<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>              .com, Finance
       .com<br><br>Finance<br><br><br><br><br>DO<br><br><br><br><br><br><br>          .com, Finance, DO
 <br><br>Finance<br><br><br>ISV<br><br>DO<br>DO Prem<br><br><br><br><br><br>  Finance, ISV, DO, DO Prem
             <br><br>Finance<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>                    Finance
          <br><br>Finance<br><br><br>TTY<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>               Finance, TTY
```

Answer (score 0):

```
### Replace br with space
df['Column 2'] = df['column 1'].str.replace('<br>', ' ')
### Get rid of spaces before and after the string
df['Column 2'] = df['Column 2'].strip()
### Replace the space with ,
df['Column 2'] = df['Column 2'].str.replace('\\s+', ',', regex=True)
```

As pointed out by TrentonMcKinney, his solution is better. This one doesn't solve the issue when there is a space between the string values in Column 1

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney I actually didn't see your comment. I had just copied the data to an ipython notebook and playing with it there.

Comment: `Finance, ISV, DO, DO Prem` is the expected output.   Your code will produce `Finance, ISV, DO, DO, Prem`.  Note the `,` between `DO` and `Prem`.

Comment: Yes, that little piece is a gotcha.